# Anyone know why issues in <style> without type attribute "text/css" in XHTML are intermittent in the issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, mask

Before you vote or answer, I know that you should use the attributes for XHTML, (actually this should be placed in its own .css) I am simply trying to understand how it is handled because of the unique results I was getting.

I found issues with a few sites I ended up taking on, that ran the CSS with what looked to be no issues at least with the CSS. It was after having a few jquery issues and slow processing that I looked to optimize. I ended up finding a common issue. It was a module holding inline CSS `<style>` tags without the type attributes. Btw, these are XHTML and not HTML5 sites. Changing the tags by adding attributes or removing the inline CSS looks to correct each site with the problems.

My question is, what is actually happening that would cause an issue to corrupt the process and still allow the CSS to function properly. This is out of pure curiosity and all style has been placed in it's own file. These are in a Joomla 1.5 module.

To really detail out one issue that happened more than once was a mask failed to complete it's process and happened to be code that followed the inline CSS. So far, this has yet to happen on 80 or so other sites with the same exact code, minus the style error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default xhtml should be validated...any deviations away from validation will inevitably lead you to a rendering engine (or 3)'s choking death.

in most (x)html versions < html5, using the type attribute and text/css value is required for validation. it is redundant, but that's certainly no reason to not use it.

offhand vague hints at what you are viewing:

sounds like the inline css is conflicting with your js, most likely you've got some scripts firing pre onload; u can wait for page load to fire them off. as long as your styles are loading properly, users will not know the difference. page loads pretty preload. page operates properly onload.

another reason for proper css rendering is the forgiving nature of most css engines; they're built with the understanding that authors can and will churn out enterprise, spaghetti front-end code. kind of like how a tank is made to roll through any and every terrain. xhtml is one of the few (that i'm aware of) instances were validation was required...if you've noticed html5's rise to power, it is clearly replacing xhtml and its strict ways. or rather, xhtml wasn't exactly a success. in some ways, forgiveness has actually made the web suck more, because author's weren't forced to operate with valid techniques. forgiveness is awesome though, it allows (some) access to old documents/horrible constructed documents

imo you should just keep on playing with the validator. remember not to focus on the validation aspect, it's a tool, just knock out errors as they come. trust me, they repeat themselves so often, if you do it enough, you won't even have to rely on it. and knowing how the user agents react within/without the scope of validation is supreme knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

The `type` attribute is redundant and, in practice, a useless risk in `style` elements, because browsers only support `text/css` (which refers to CSS generically) and default to it. Any other value, such as the typo `text/ccs`, causes the element content to be ignored.

In client-side scripting, though, it is possible to use code that for example removes `style` elements without `type` attribute or somehow uses the content of such elements depending on the attribute. It would be odd, and I would expect it to be a programming error more probably than intentional checking or trickery.

Whether the `type` attribute is formally required depends on HTML version and does not affect what browsers or scripts do.

Comment: Yes by skipping the `type` attribute we will be relying on the browser's way of handling errors which will always be unpredictable.

Comment: It is an error in a formal sense only and depending on HTML version, as I mentioned; in HTML 3.2, the `style` attribute was not required or even allowed; in HTML5, it will have the defined default of `text/css`, as it has always had in any browser that recognizes the element in the first place.

Comment: The only thing is this is associated before and after XHTML as Zafar stated in the later answer. I have written style without attributes in HTML5 just as I have not commented out script. In fact I did find similar problems running inline script in XHTML with improper commenting of the script.

Answer (score 1):

According to W3C default is "text/css" if none set and examples in docs don't have `type` set

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/style

Might have to chalk it up to one of those "little wonders" that make debugging interesting.

Answer (score 1):

No I disagree with the answer given by @charlietfi. It's optional in case of HTML and it will default to `"text/css"` is not present only in case of HTML.

For XHTML it is a required field. You can test it my create an XHTML markup without the `type` attribute for the `style` tag. This is what you will get:
**required attribute "type" not specified**

To try it yourself, please visit the authentic W3C validation site:
http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I did actually get this error through the CSS validation. I was also wondering if the issue could be unique to the combination of type attribute and the RSForm Pro module it was in. The script that showed issues was in that module as well. Also there is an RSSEO module that has been known to wig out in previous versions in it's automation features. I figure these might be relevant to at least adding to the issue.